# Generate pdf with form data on form submission

Tags: jsf, itext, jsf-1.2

I have a simple JSF form which has 2 fields, user and email and a submit button, I would like to show the same form data in readonly mode in a new PDF.

[image]

Consider the form has a submit button. How can I get the Image of the submitted form or the exact form data with my labels and styles, in my backing JSF bean, so that I can write the data to a PDF.

**Update:**
I am looking at Flying Saucer API that would do this, along with Itext API.

Comment: Please clarify. Take a look at http://demo.itextsupport.com/itextsamples/ and click the "fill" or "flatten" link. Fill out the HTML form and submit. Is that what you want to do? If so, watch the video tutorial: http://itextpdf.com/codenvy_webapp If not, please clarify.

Comment: Flatten is readonly which is nice, but this is not, what I wanted to do exactly. The form in that examples are using a predefined pdf template and writing request parameters into the pdf which has its own layout and style. I am trying to achieve exact image of the form including the style and layout in the form of pdf upon submit.

Comment: What is the exact image of the form in the context of your question? HTML? HTML isn't an image format, nor should HTML be used to define a layout.

Comment: No. I mean, the pdf should have the labels from the FORM and css styles applied including the images in form, all must be appeared in the pdf.

Comment: Am I understanding you correctly when I interpret your question as "I want the complete form (HTML, CSS, data) to be *magically* sent to the browser?" Or did I simplify your question too much? If so, unsimplify your question.